# pandasql OperationalError: too many SQL variables

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I'm trying to work with `pandasql` but something is not working properly. I execute the following code:

```
from pandasql import sqldf, load_meat
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
meat = load_meat()
df = pysqldf("SELECT * FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()
```

and get this error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) too many SQL variables [SQL: 'INSERT INTO meat (date, beef, veal, pork, lamb_and_mutton, broilers, other_chicken, turkey) VALUES
```

and

```
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: does your load_meat function inserting values in a table ?

Comment: `meat = load_meat` loads a dataframe into `meat` (you can test it yourself with the code I provided)

Comment: I am using Py27 Spyder IDE and it is working fine for me!!

Comment: I'm using Python3 and Spyder IDE

Answer (score 1):

This is due to pandas 23.0 version. If you upgrade to pandas 23.4, your problem will be fixed. Use pip install --upgrade pandas (with root privileges) or pip install --user --upgrade pandas (without root privileges).